# Javascript Bootstrap Navbar Color Change Not as Expected

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want my navbar to change background color when the offcanvas menu is opened and revert back to the original color when the offcanvas is closed. I managed to find the classes that are applied to the offcanvas menu when it's fired and made it work with the only exception that if you click on the navbar or anywhere else in the DOM while having the offcanvas open the color still changes :( I was hoping to get some help and prevent the color from changing when you randomly click in the DOM and have the navbar change color only when the offcanvas is closed as it was intended. You can watch it live here: https://reliable-stardust-881a63.netlify.app/

```
const navBar = document.querySelector("#offcanvas-navbar");
const fixedTop = document.querySelector("body > nav");
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (navBar.classList.contains('showing' || 'show')) {
        fixedTop.style.backgroundColor = '#ff2fac';
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        fixedTop.style.backgroundColor = '#adff2f';
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `OR` logic in the `classList.contains()` method.

`if (navBar.classList.contains('showing' || 'show')) {`

It should be like this

`if (navBar.classList.contains('showing') || navBar.classList.contains('show')) {`

EDIT:
To answer the question of "prevent the color from changing when you randomly click in the DOM" is to attach onclick handlers to the buttons themselves.

```
const openOffCanvasBtn = document.querySelector('button[data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"]'); 
const closeOffCanvasBtn = document.querySelector('button[data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"]');

openOffCanvasBtn.onclick = () => {
  fixedTop.style.backgroundColor = '#ff2fac';
}
closeOffCanvasBtn.onclick = () => {
  fixedTop.style.backgroundColor = '#adff2f';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen I corrected the syntax as advised but this interferes with the function and somehow ruins it. Now the color change still occurs but doesn't revert back to the original when the offcanvas is closed unless you click once anywhere in the DOM.

Comment: That's because you're attaching a click listener to the document. Attach a listener to the offcanvas close button to change the color back.